# Asterisk + Webrtc no sound

Tags: asterisk, webrtc

Использую Sipml5 + asterisk для работы. По ws все хорошо работает, но когда пытаюсь использовать wss - звонок идет, а звука нет.

Сертификат купленный и валидный, хром отмечает зеленым и вроде не ругается. 
Когда ставлю звонок на удержание - слышу музыку, снимаю с удержания - снова тишина.

Даже не знаю куда копать, и какие данные предоставить чтобы мне кто-то смог помочь.

Логи RTP говорят нам что трафик ходит:

```
 Got  RTP packet from    89.162.254.10:19262 (type 08, seq 047185, ts 2078847540, len 000160)
 Sent RTP packet to      93.183.211.107:4364 (type 00, seq 031006, ts 2078847536, len 000160)
 Got  RTP packet from    89.162.254.10:19262 (type 08, seq 047186, ts 2078847700, len 000160)
 Sent RTP packet to      93.183.211.107:4364 (type 00, seq 031007, ts 2078847696, len 000160)
 Got  RTP packet from    89.162.254.10:19262 (type 08, seq 047187, ts 2078847860, len 000160)
 Sent RTP packet to      93.183.211.107:4364 (type 00, seq 031008, ts 2078847856, len 000160)
 Got  RTP packet from    89.162.254.10:19262 (type 08, seq 047188, ts 2078848020, len 000160)
 Sent RTP packet to      93.183.211.107:4364 (type 00, seq 031009, ts 2078848016, len 000160)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос решился тем что при подключении вместо ip стоило указать доменное имя - и все корректно заработало.